# Keep files updated in another Sharepoint folder

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am trying to make a "Power-automate"/"Flow" in Sharepoint that is keeping a target folder updated with all the changes that is made in another Sharepoint folder (source).

I have "played around" with the functionality, but I am having an issue:

My problem is if there are subfolders in the Source folder, then I would like to also update or create the document in the same folder in the target folder.

Ex.

All documents and folders in this folder "docs" shall be updated in the target folder:

```
/my documents/docs/
/my documents/docs/mydoc.docx
/my documents/docs/subfolder/doc2.docx
```

There can be files directly in the "docs" folder or in sub folders, and all shall be create/updated in the target folder. But how do I keep the folder structure from the source folder in the target folder?

Thanks very much for your time :-)

Comment: Is your PowerAutomate flow allowed to execute Powershell script or code?

Comment: I am not sure, where can I see that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing some replacing on the full path for the file, and it looks like it is working :-)